# How to save new registrations to another database hosted in the same hosting site

Tags: database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am working on a wordpress site and I need to save the form registrations from the main site at the same time to the subdomain database. I'm using godaddy as the hosting service and contact form 7 for the forms.

Can someone help me? Thank you so much

Comment: Is the same WP website database or different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you get Contact Form 7 request

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_mail_components', 'show_cf7_request', 10, 3 );
function show_cf7_request( $components, $wpcf7_get_current_contact_form, $instance ) { 
    post_to_another_url('https://site-to.post', $_REQUEST);
    return $components; 
};
```

and forward id to another url as JSON POST

```
function post_to_another_url($url, $data {
    if(is_array($data) && $url != '') {
        // copied from => https://tecadmin.net/post-json-data-php-curl/
        $payload = json_encode($data);

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);

        // Set HTTP Header for POST request 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($payload))
        );

        // Submit the POST request
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        // Close cURL session handle
        curl_close($ch);
    }
}
```

if you want insert data in same database, but different table, use `$wpdb->insert()` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/